# Debug vs solution called by a running vs solution

Tags: c#, debugging, process

Let's say we have (mainSolution) and (secondarySolution). The mainSolution calls files from the secondarySolution, and I need to debug the second one.
The problem is, I run the mainSolution, go to the second one, debug by attaching process to the first one. But then no breakpoints from the second solution are hit. I have already seen the videos that explain to change release to debug mode, but just that doesn't seem to work.

How can I debug a solution called by other.
Thanks all.

Comment: Solution is just a placeholder for collection of projects. The code that runs is actually part of a project. Can you tells us how the projects inside of both the solutions are laid out and which project refers which project?

Comment: Yes, Basically the Main solution makes an ajax request to the second solution.